# How to replace quotation marks within JSON dictionary value?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm using [Open Trivia DB](https://opentdb.com/)'s API to generate trivia questions.

```py
import requests, json, urllib.parse
import 

url = "https://opentdb.com/api.php"

querystring = {"amount":"5","type":"multiple","encode":"url3986"}

response = requests.request("GET", url, params=querystring)
response_decoded = urllib.parse.unquote(response.text)
print(response_decoded)
response_dict = json.loads(response_decoded)
print(response_dict["results"][0])
```

However, I keep on running into an error one some occurrences, the error being:

```py
Exception has occurred: JSONDecodeError
Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 347 (char 346)
```

I've worked out that the error is because in some questions similar to `Who is the main character in "gamename"`, there are quotation marks around gamename. In the context of the JSON I was returned it looks like this:

```py
"question":"Who is the main character in "gamename"?",
"correct_answer":"maincharacter",
"incorrect_answers":["wrongname1","wrongname2","wrongname3"]
```

and the quotation marks around the gamename is messing the dictionary up.

Is there a way for me to replace the inner quotation marks only (around the gamename) to singular quotation marks, `'`, so that it doesn't mess up the dictionary structure?

Comment: I don't know much about `json` but in python you can include double quotes in a string like this: `'this is a string with a " double quote inside single quotes'`

Comment: @Merp yeah but the thing is that I get given a whole dictionary with the different questions. I can't just do replace() because that'll replace all quotation marks and then i have the same issue again. I would need a way of replacing some quotation marks but not others.

Comment: By decoding the raw string, you are causing the JSON to become malformed. Instead, you can `json.loads` it first. When you need to output any part of it, then you can decode each individual string with `urllib`. An alternative approach that is more fragile is to do something like `response_decoded = urllib.parse.unquote(response.text.replace('"', '~')).replace('"', r'\"').replace('~', '"')`.

Comment: Thanks @iz_ ! if you'd like, you could post it as an answer and I'll mark it as answered. It's a great idea and I didn't think of that for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't parse the response yourself. Use `requests` for that and it will handle the quotes:

```
import requests

resp = requests.get(
    "https://opentdb.com/api.php",
    params={"amount": "5", "type": "multiple", "encode": "url3986"},
)
resp.raise_for_status()  # raise an Exception if the HTTP response failed
data = resp.json()  # Parse JSON from the response
print(data["results"][0])  # print it
```

Looking at the data, some of the inner fields appear URL-encoded. Use `urllib.parse.unquote` for these:

```
import urllib.parse

print(urllib.parse.unquote("Entertainment%3A%20Music"))  # Entertainment: Music
```

Answer (score 1):

By decoding the raw string, you are causing the JSON to become malformed. Instead, you can `json.loads` it first. When you need to output any part of it, then you can decode each individual string with `urllib`.

An alternative approach that is more fragile is to do something like

```
response_decoded = urllib.parse.unquote(response.text.replace('"', '~')).replace('"', r'\"').replace('~', '"').
```

You can use a different character than `~` if you experience any issues; I just chose something uncommon.